# use of storyboard in multi developer

Tags: ios, git

I am planning to start an iOS project in bilingual, so I preferred to create a Storyboard project as baseline. During the project there may be 2 more developer will join hands to complete this at earlier. We are following the git flow process using bitbucket. But my question is how to solve the conflict issues in storyboard as it show in binary values were we can't able to resolve this. Because every developer will work on their tasks of their own with design too. Have anyone faced this already and had any ideas about this, kindly suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can make a base storyboard and for each developer they should make their storyboard according to functionality divided in them.we have done in this way.and link storyboards programatically.

Comment: Normally storyboard files would be presented in the XML format. If the conflicts are not too bad we will solve them using just a text editor. Sometimes it's clear that we choose one of them wholesale. Some other times a conflict is so bad that I would just copy one version, put it somewhere else. Open another version and copy view controllers from the other one and paste them there. This might not answer your question but it's just what we do :'(

Comment: Thank you johny and sikhapol.